# Reading from file and splitting in seperate lists

Tags: python, list, readfile

Reading from file. Then trying to split lines into different lists.

```
userID = []
fname = []
lname = []
email = []
salary = []
nextLine = file.readline()
while nextLine != '':
    filedata = file.readline().rstrip()
    userID.append(filedata)
    filedata = file.readline().rstrip()
    fname.append(filedata)
    filedata = file.readline().rstrip()
    lname.append(filedata)
    filedata = file.readline().rstrip()
    email.append(filedata)
    filedata = file.readline().rstrip()
    salary.append(filedata)
    nextLine = file.readline()
file.close()
print(userID)
```

I'm trying to get the program to put each line of the code into the seperate files listed below, and to keep doing this until the file ends

Result: The program keeps looping and never ends

Comment: You never assing a new value to `nextLine` inside the `while` loop. The loop condition never changes.

Comment: BTW the lists should be initialized outside of the loop.

Comment: Ah yes, I fixed that now, all lists are initialized outside of loop.

Answer (score 1):

You read only first line from your input file, and then you loop forever because your loop lacks new reads, so `while` won't ever be evaluated to `False` due to lack of new data read . Just add

```
nextLine = file.readline()
```

**at the end** of your loop block and you should be good.

Comment: Ah that fixed the infinite loop error, i'm still getting wrong output tho, not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```py
import itertools

userID, fname, lname, email, salary = [], [], [], [], []
lists = itertools.cycle([userID, fname, lname, email, salary])

with open("in_file.txt") as infile:
    for line, append_list in zip(infile, lists):
        append_list.append(line)
```

Your lists should now be populated.